# How to extract all non-nan values in this dataframe by the non-nan values count of each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract the non-nan values in each row of dataframe.
I get a dataframe whose number of rows is more than 3000 as follows:

```
# this is just an example, not whole data
  l1     l2     l3
0 2      nan    nan
1 1      nan    nan
2 3      4      nan
3 1      2      4
4 3      2      nan
5 4      1      2
6 5      nan    nan
```

And I want to extract all non-nan values in this dataframe by the non-nan values count of each row like follows

```
one_non_nan_value_counts
    l1
0   2
1   1
2   5

two_non_nan_value_counts
    l1    l2    
0   3     4
1   3     2

three_non_nan_value_counts
    l1    l2    l3
0   1     2     4
1   4     1     2
```

Could any help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
for x,y in df.groupby(df.isna().sum(axis=1)):
    print('nan', x)
    print(y.dropna(axis=1))
```

output:

```
nan 0
   l1   l2   l3
3   1  2.0  4.0
5   4  1.0  2.0
nan 1
   l1   l2
2   3  4.0
4   3  2.0
nan 2
   l1
0   2
1   1
6   5
```